# No response from the server- Loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, loopbackjs, strongloop

Sometimes there is no response from loopback. This occurring in both development and production mode.

Code is a simple one that used to check whether the user is logged in or not.
Also, any console that wrote on the code does not work in the same cases.
I think the call not connecting the api, otherwise, at least console will work.

```
Lead.isLogedIn = function (req, cb) {
console.log("inside logged innnn")
    var data = {}
    var Survey = app.models.survey;
    data.loggedStatus = false;
    if (req.accessToken && req.accessToken.userId) {
        data.loggedStatus = true;
        Lead.findById(req.accessToken.userId, (err, leadData) => {
            if (err) return cb(err)
            Survey.find({ where: { lead_id: req.accessToken.userId, status: false } }, (err, surveyData) => {
                if (err) return cb(err)
                console.log("Inside survey detials get")
                if (leadData)
                    data.leadData = leadData.toJSON();
                data.surveyData = surveyData;
                return cb(null, data);
            })
        })
    } else
        return cb(null, data)
}

Lead.remoteMethod('isLogedIn', {
    accepts: { "arg": "req", "type": "object", "http": { source: 'req' } },
    returns: { arg: 'data', type: 'object' },
    description: "check Whether users has valid token or not",
    "http": { verb: "get" }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You NEED to post one [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried and what is happening and also what is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Updated the question. This api called from the frontend side. But not getting responses in sometimes.

Comment: try to run it with the env variable `export DEBUG=*` to debug what is happening. I would also try debugger or a bunch of console log to make sure if the method is called and where it stops working

Comment: Yes, i don't think there is a problem with the function itself. Maybe your frontend is not connecting to loopback server itself.

Comment: Okay. Let me try